# Generating fixtures from database in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fixtures

I want to generate fixtures from the development database in Rails 3.1. I tried using the yaml files created by yaml_db, but their structure is different from that of fixtures.

I am trying to get ar_fixtures to work, I put

> gem 'ar_fixtures'

in my Gemfile and did a bundle install but "rake -T" doesnt show anything new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That gem is years old and not 3.1 compatible likely. If you're ok with the fixtures being dumped into a single file, check out the 'yaml_db' gem on github

Comment: Thanks, yeah I have been using yaml_db for a couple of weeks now it works well.

Comment: It has also :dump_dirs and :load_dirs tasks which use one yaml file per table.